# "multiple target patterns" make error

Tags: makefile, build

I've have this error while compiling [improved trajectories](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/~wang/improved_trajectories)

`.build_release/DenseTrackStab.l:2: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.`

.build_release/DenseTrackStab.l file:

```
-include .build_release/DenseTrackStab.d
.build_release/DenseTrackStab.l: \
    .build_release/DenseTrackStab.d \
release/DenseTrackStab: .build_release/DenseTrackStab.l \
    .build_release/DenseTrackStab.o \
```

Comment: The 4 line-continations ( \ ) join lines into a single line, as far as `make` is
concerned, and that one long line doesn't make sense.

Comment: should I remove "\" in the 3rd line?

Comment: You should use a \-line-continuation only when you want split one long make-statement over more than one line.

Comment: This is an auto-generated file, I haven't write that. That's why I find it strange that it could have a syntax error. I think removing "\" from 3rd line fixed it.